# RegExp replace only if not within <tag> and </tag>

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

We are using a RegExp replace to searching a text for terms and wrap the hits with `<dfn>`. This works like a charm until we have a term that contains of several words that get wrapped and then a term that only has one of those words. For example:

These are an example for one of these cases with the terms:
"Human Design System", "Design".

So our code first finds "Human Design System", wraps it with a `<dfn>` tag and then finds "Design" within that and wraps that with an `<dfn>` tag.

The result becomes:

```
<dfn>Human <dfn>Design</dfn> System</dfn>
```

When we desire the result:

```
<dfn>Human Design System</dfn>
```

So what we need is a way of checking if the term is wrapped by a `<dfn></dfn>` and simply skip the replace for these cases.

This is the code we are using right now:

```
//Definition of variables, please not that ~open~ is replaced by <dfn> and ~close~ is replaced by </dfn> later  
var TPL_TAG_OPEN = '~open~',
    TPL_TAG_CLOSE = '~close~',
    ESCAPERS = '[\\s!:\.\;,%\"\'\\(\\)\\{\\}]';

//This is the RegExp that prepares the content
//term is the term that we are looking for and line is the text we are searching in

var re = new RegExp("^("+term+")(" + ESCAPERS + ")", modifier);
line = line.replace(re, TPL_TAG_OPEN + "$1" + TPL_TAG_CLOSE + "$2");

re = new RegExp("(" + ESCAPERS + ")("+term+")$", modifier);
line = line.replace(re, "$1" + TPL_TAG_OPEN + "$2" + TPL_TAG_CLOSE);

re = new RegExp("(" + ESCAPERS + ")("+term+")(" + ESCAPERS + ")", modifier);
line = line.replace(re, "$1" + TPL_TAG_OPEN +"$2" + TPL_TAG_CLOSE + "$3");
```

Input:

```
<dfn>Human Design System</dfn> Human Design Design Human Testar test Human Design Test 
Human Test Design Test Test Design <dfn>Human Design System</dfn> Test Human Design
```

Result right now:

```
<dfn>Human <dfn>Design</dfn> System</dfn> Human <dfn>Design</dfn <dfn>Design</dfn> 
Human Testar test Human <dfn>Design</dfn Test Human Test <dfn>Design</dfn> Test Test
<dfn>Design</dfn> <dfn>Human <dfn>Design</dfn> System</dfn> Test Human <dfn>Design</dfn>
```

Wanted Result:

```
<dfn>Human Design System</dfn> Human <dfn>Design</dfn> <dfn>Design</dfn> 
Human Testar test Human <dfn>Design</dfn> Test Human Test <dfn>Design</dfn> 
Test Test <dfn>Design</dfn> <dfn>Human Design System</dfn> Test Human <dfn>Design</dfn>
```

Note:

We have succeeded to check if the term is wrapped by the tag already but only with the RegExp .test function, but if this will prevent the text to go on and check the rest of the text, here is that code:

```
var pattern = RegExp("^("+TPL_TAG_OPEN+").*((?!"+TPL_TAG_CLOSE+").).*("+term+")*$");

if (pattern.test(line))
     return false;
```

Final solution:

```
var ESCAPERS = '[\\s!:\.\;,%\"\'\\(\\)\\{\\}]';
var terms = ['Design','Human Design System','This and That...'];
terms = terms.join('|');
re = new RegExp("(" + ESCAPERS + "|^)(" + terms + ")(" + ESCAPERS + "|$)",'gi');
nodes.contents().filter()
     .each(function(){
          $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace(re, '$1<dfn class=\"thesaurus\">$2</dfn>$3'));
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it all in one pass:

```js
var s = 'Human Design System Human Design Design Human Testar test ' +
        'Human Design Test Human Test Design Test Test Design Human ' +
        'Design System Test Human Design';

// Alternative matches are tried in sequence.
var t = s.replace(/Human Design System|Design/g, '<dfn>$&</dfn>');

console.log(t);
```

Or, to do it incrementally:

```js
var s = 'Human Design System Human Design Design Human Testar test ' +
        'Human Design Test Human Test Design Test Test Design Human ' +
        'Design System Test Human Design';

var adddfn = function(s, term){
    return s.replace(/(.*?)(<dfn>.*?<\/dfn>|$)/g, function(all, one, two){
        return one.replace(RegExp(term, 'g'), '<dfn>$&</dfn>') + two;
    });
};

var terms = ['Human Design System', 'Design'];

var t = terms.reduce(function(result, term){
    return adddfn(result, term);
}, s);

console.log(t);
```

Comment: We have over hundreds of terms that needs to be replaced, although your suggestion might make sense and I will investigate if this would be a better approach!

Comment: Thanks for your first answer, after some refinement we got it to work much better and faster than the code from the plugin we where using!

Answer (score 0):

These also another way but a single regex cant able to do.

Find this match design   `(<dfn>(?:(?!</?dfn>).)* )design( (?:(?!</?dfn>).)*</dfn>)`

substitute design with `$1&tmp;$2`

then find `Design` in match and replace with `<dfn>$&</dfn>`

now match inside the dfn `&tmp;` in  `(<dfn>(?:(?!</?dfn>).)* )&tmp;( (?:(?!</?dfn>).)*</dfn>)`

change to `$1Design$2`

now the problem solved.

If you want make use of it with above code.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but did you really get my question? what you are looking for is anything that is within <dfn>, what we need is a query for the replace that replaces all "terms" except if term is within <dfn></dfn>

Comment: Give some example. what is your Input and required Output.

Comment: Input and wanted result added

Comment: I have edited the code. This is another way u should your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just match tags that are already there and pass them through:

```js
str = "<dfn>Human Design System</dfn> Human Design Design Human Testar test Human Design Test Human Test Design Test Test Design <dfn>Human Design System</dfn> Test Human Design";

str = str.replace(/(<dfn>.+?<\/dfn>)|(Human Design System|Design)/g, function(_, $1, $2) {
    return $1 || "<dfn>" + $2 + "</dfn>";
});

alert(str)
```